# Foam/Poly Jacking Garage Floor?

Tags: repair, foundation, slab

The door jambs on the two exterior hinged doors for my garage are becoming an issue with being out of square.  The floor is otherwise pretty much OK (no cracks, etc.)  The floor is part of a 6" or 8" thick post-tensioned slab.  I think this issue is mostly due to soil erosion underneath, although it may just be settling at this point as well (the house is about 25 years old).  Is poly jacking in a few appropriate places, i.e. wherever needed, a reasonable solution?

I understand that eventually a professional will need to assess and effect any repairs, but I also wanted to check with the Team DIY-SE if I was barking up the wrong tree with the poly jack approach.

Comment: Are the walls of the garage attached to another building?

Comment: Jacking/tensioning the base slab is out of the realm of DIY. You can do patching and squaring the jamb by yourself, then leave everything else to the expert.

Comment: @crip659: Yes, it's an attached garage...all part of the same house structure.

Comment: @r13: As mentioned I realize I'll need a professional; my goal posting here was just to get whatever wisdom of the cord might be available in general before talking with them, i.e. forewarned is forearmed.

Comment: Should you buy a prescription from an unknown web seller? It's your health/safety. But good luck.